# Hide button when user is scrolling in the browser, and fade button back in when they're done

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to hide a button with the id #stats when the user is scrolling, and then I want it to fade back in when they're done scrolling.

For some reason this is not working below.

Thanks for any help!

```
<button id="stats">
    <span class="icon prs">&#59146;</span><h3 id="views" class="prm">@file.views</h3>
    <span class="icon prs">&#59160;</span><h3 id="comments">20</h3>       
</button><!--end stats-->


<script>
    //fade stats in on load
    $(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
        $('#stats').hide().fadeIn('slow');
    });

    //hide stats when scrolling
    var $stats = $("#stats");
    var opacity = $stats.css("opacity");
    var scrollStopped;

    var fadeInCallback = function () {
        if (typeof scrollStopped != 'undefined') {
            clearInterval(scrollStopped);
        }

        scrollStopped = setTimeout(function () {
            $stats.animate({ opacity: 1 }, "slow");
        }, 200);
    };

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (!$stats.is(":animated") && opacity == 1) {
            $stats.animate({ opacity: 0 }, "slow", fadeInCallback);
        } else {
            fadeInCallback.call(this);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you moved the `var opacity = ...` to the `scroll` callback - to get the **current** value instead of the one in the beginning of the script (`0`) - you'd be 90% of the way done. But since @adeneo already presented a simpler alternative, I'd go with that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try to simplify it a little, and do something more like this:

```
$(function(){
    var stats = $('#stats'),
        vis   = true;
        timer,


    stats.hide().fadeIn('slow');
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        if (vis) {
            stats.stop(true,true).fadeOut('slow');
            vis = false;
        }
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            stats.stop(true,true).fadeIn('slow');
            vis = true;
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWx94/)

Comment: if you scroll at just the right pace you can keep it going for a long time. best to put a `.stop()` in there http://jsfiddle.net/ZWx94/1/

Comment: @Mark - You'd need to have some strange scrolling habits to notice that problem, and stops are rarely needed on the fading functions in jQuery, but I did test it, and noticed that if you really put your mind to it, you could make it repeat, so I'll add the stops in the code above. Thanks!

Comment: :-) Even without timing it perfectly, I find it to be more pleasing if it fades back out right away when I start scrolling again rather than waiting for it to fully fade back in. I find 99% of the time `.stop()` is preferable when dealing with animations.